# How can I get a String as a return from an Arc Mutex

Tags: string, rust, getter-setter

Here is the code.

```rust
use std::sync::{ Arc, Mutex };

fn main() {
    let test_s = Test{ s: Arc::new(Mutex::new(String::new())) };
    test_s.setter(String::from("whatever"));
    println!("{}", test_s.getter())
}

struct Test {
    s: Arc<Mutex<String>>,
}

impl Test {
    pub fn getter(&self) -> String {
        *self.s.lock().unwrap() // Error occured here !
    }
    
    pub fn setter(&self, s: String) {
        *self.s.lock().unwrap() = s
    }
}
```

And here is the Error output

```bash
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0507]: cannot move out of dereference of `MutexGuard<'_, String>`
  --> src/main.rs:15:9
   |
15 |         *self.s.lock().unwrap()
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ move occurs because value has type `String`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0507`.
error: could not compile `playground` due to previous error
```

I can get the `s` value just use `test_s.s.lock().unwrap()`, and use it as a `&str` just with `&test_s.s.lock().unwrap()`

Is there an easy way to return a `String`?

Comment: You may also want to consider: do you want a reference to the string, or do you want a clone of the string?  And do you want a "move" to occur, or not?  You're returning a brand-new object with your return type of `String`, so ensure that's what you intend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to deref directly there (`*`), also you will need to `Clone` the `String`:

```rust
...
    pub fn getter(&self) -> String {
         self.s.lock().unwrap().clone()
    }
...
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9771e5dff37d10cddf4163b746be682a)

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively return the `MutextGuard`, which derefs to the underlying type. You won't have to clone the string. You won't need the `setter` anymore. But you'll have to remember to drop the guard before using the `getter` again.

```
use std::sync::{ Arc, Mutex, MutexGuard };

fn main() {
    let test_s = Test{ s: Arc::new(Mutex::new(String::new())) };

    {
        let mut s = test_s.getter();
        s.push_str("what");
        // MutexGuard s is dropped here - lock is released
    }
    println!("{}", test_s.getter());

    {
        let mut s = test_s.getter();
        *s = "whatever".to_string();
        // MutexGuard s is dropped here - lock is released
    }
    println!("{}", test_s.getter());
}

struct Test {
    s: Arc<Mutex<String>>,
}

impl Test {
    pub fn getter(&self) -> MutexGuard<String> {
        self.s.lock().unwrap()
    }
}
```